# Convert a (n_samples, n_features) ndarray to a (n_samples, 1) array of vectors to use as training labels for an sklearn SVM

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, encoding, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate the ROC and AUC for an SVM model I'm building. I'm following the code from [this sklearn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html). One of the requirements is that the output labels `y` need to be binarized. I do this by using creating a `MultiLabelBinarizer` and encode all the labels, which works fine. However, this creates a (n_samples, n_features) ndarray. The `classifier.fit(X, y)` function assumes `y.shape = (n_samples)`. I want to essentially "smush" the columns of `y` together, so that y[0][0] would return the entire feature-vector, `V`, instead of just the first value of `V`.

Here's my code:

```
    enc = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    print("Encoding data...")
    # Fit the encoder onto all possible data values
    print(pandas.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(df["present"] + df["member"].apply(str).apply(lambda x: [x])),
                           columns=enc.classes_, index=df.index))
    X, y = enc.transform(df["present"]), list(df["member"].apply(str))
    print("Training svm...")
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5, random_state=0)
    y_train = enc.transform([[x] for x in y_train])  # Strings to 1HotVectors
    svc = svm.SVC(C=1.1, kernel="linear", probability=True, class_weight='balanced')
    svc.fit(X_train, y_train)  # y_train should be 1D but isn't
```

The exception I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SawyerPC/PycharmProjects/DiscordSocialGraph/encode_and_train.py", line 129, in <module>
    enc, clf, split_data = encode_and_train(df)
  File "C:/Users/SawyerPC/PycharmProjects/DiscordSocialGraph/encode_and_train.py", line 57, in encode_and_train
    svc.fit(X_train, y_train)  # TODO y_train needs to be flattened to (n_samples,)
  File "C:\Users\SawyerPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 149, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
  File "C:\Users\SawyerPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 547, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "C:\Users\SawyerPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 583, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (5000, 10)
```

Comment: The purpose of `multilabelbinarizer` is to encode the labels in the "supported multilabel format: a (samples x classes) binary matrix indicating the presence of a class label." What is the error given when you try to run the `.fit()` method?

Comment: @G.Anderson I added the full stack trace of the exception in my question.

Comment: I can't find anything regarding this issue, but can you switch to using `LabelEncoder` instead of 'multilabelbinarizer`?

Comment: I tried using a `OneVsRestClassifier` to wrap around the SVC, like suggested in the tutorial. This essentially adds a `LabelEncoder` to the SVC behind the scenes. The only problem now is that `classifier.classes_` now returns the Encoded Labels instead of the Strings, which conflicts with `MTB.classes_` which I compare against sometimes. `OneVsRestClassifier` has a `LabelBinarizer_` member, so I thought I could `inverse_transform` using that, but it's not the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like you've done everything right, and short of trying a different route altogether I'm afraid I can't help more than this. Hopefully someone else will see this and can help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using a `LabelEncoder`. Thanks @G.Anderson. The `flat_member_list` is just a list of all the unique user ids encountered both in the labels `y`, and the vectors `X`.

```
# Encode "present" users as OneHotVectors
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print("Encoding data...")
mlb.fit(df["present"] + df["member"].apply(str).apply(lambda x: [x]))

# Encode user labels as ints
enc = LabelEncoder()
flat_member_list = df["member"].apply(str).append(pandas.Series(np.concatenate(df["present"]).ravel()))
enc.fit(flat_member_list)
X, y = mlb.transform(df["present"]), enc.transform(df["member"].apply(str))
print("Training svm...")
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5, random_state=0, stratify=y)
svc = svm.SVC(C=0.317, kernel="linear", probability=True)
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```